# Singularity build failure due to groupadd for openssh-client installation

Tags: ubuntu, apt, singularity

In Singularity when building under fake-root anything Ubuntu based with in `%post` either `apt update -y` or `apt install -y openssh-client` or their `apt-get` versions or with `-f` in the definition file fails fatally with

```
groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group
addgroup: `/sbin/groupadd -g 101 ssh' returned error code 10. Exiting.
Errors were encountered while processing: openssh-client E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
FATAL: While performing build: while running engine: exit status 100
```

I see why adding a user is an issue, but `yum update` works fine in Rocky 9 (I cannot switch to it due to some requirements). This is on a cluster where I do NOT have root priviledges and have to use Singularity and docker isn't available —the base OS is CentOS 7 and glibc issues are insurmountable.
I have tried a bunch of different Ubuntu images, ranging from Nvidia's Docker Ubuntu image and officially signed to unsigned Singularity images.

Conda can install ssh, but the issue is `apt update` fails and I cannot work around it.

I feel like I missing something obvious based on the lack of much on this online...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is spoofing the package manager via [equivs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/equivs-build.1.html)

```bash
apt-get install -y equivs
# Manual `equivs-control openssh-client`
echo 'Section: misc' > openssh-client
echo 'Priority: optional' > openssh-client
echo 'Standards-Version: 3.9.2' > openssh-client
echo 'Package: openssh-client' > openssh-client
echo 'Version: 1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.4' > openssh-client
echo 'Maintainer: Your Name <yourname@example.com>' > openssh-client
echo 'Provides: openssh-client' > openssh-client
echo 'Architecture: amd64' > openssh-client
echo 'Description: fake package' > openssh-client
equivs-build openssh-client
dpkg -i equivs-dummy_1.0_all.deb
```